# Convert Uncompressed AVI to JPEG2000 in MXF

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm looking to convert raw, uncompressed video (currently in avi container) into lossless motion jpeg2000 encoded video in an mxf container. I've tried FFMPEG, but don't think it can do this. What's the best method for transcoding on Linux?

FFMPEG command tried:
 `ffmpeg -i Glueck_Newsreel.avi -vcodec libopenjpeg -acodec copy ms0001.mxf`

Errors:
`[mxf @ 0x1f43a00] track 0: could not find essence container ul, codec not currently supported in container`
`Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPEG 2000 codec in FFMPEG is still experimental. To use it you would have to compile FFMPEG by yourself with a special option enabled.

But you could use [OpenDCP](http://opendcp.org/), which has it's [documentation here](http://code.google.com/p/opendcp/wiki/Documentation). It needs TIFF images and WAV files as input, that you can produce with FFMPEG. The resulting MXF can be tested with the [easyDCP player](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/bf/bsy/download/easydcpplayer.html).

OpenDCP is available on all mayor platforms, but the easyDCP player only on Windows/Mac. But perhaps this is still an option for you, since you only need to run the easyDCP player once (on a friend's PC), just to be sure that the OpenDCP output is "according to the standard".

Comment: FFmpeg [won't put JPEG2000 in MXF](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1542), even with the codec enabled.